# iOS 6 UILabels show without formatting

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, formatting, uilabel

*This is an iOS 6 Question.

Since updating to [Redacted] when I build/run in iOS6 any of my UILabels that are set in Xibs and have their values set dynamically lose all formatting and become plain left justified text. They display correctly in [Redacted] and used to display correctly in iOS 6.

Note: I'm not setting attributed text just plain text in the XIBs.

Please help! I need to get this sorted out.

*Please keep the topic on iOS6 and avoid any areas covered under NDA.

[image: iOS6 Without formatting]

Comment: Most likely your project was updated by Xcode 5 in a way that messes up Xcode 4.6. You need to rollback to a copy of your project from before ever opening it in Xcode 5.

Comment: My xCode 5 stuff is working on a branch off the main code. However I would like to move forward on the branch and eventually merge it back into the main branch (sooner rather then later) there are just a few issues that need to be sorted out (this being the main one).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating an outlet to the UILabel and changing the alignment in your viewWillAppear. Sort of a hack, but I get the feeling you're running into a temporary bug.